# Ajuda com método para adicionar novo item

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, framework

Boa tarde

Tenho esta tela de vendas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver selecionei um produto, defini a quantidade e os valores foram setados automaticamente.

Agora minha ideia é, para adicionar um novo item, com os mesmos campos, comportamentos etc, basta clicar no botão adicionar novo item, e automaticamente os campos Produto, Quantidade, Valor Unitario e Valor Total Item, apareceram novamente na tela, ficando desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?

Eu comecei criando um metodo void:

```
private void adicionaNovoItem() {
    
}
```

e vou chama-lo dentro do evento do botão

```
btnAdicionarItem.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    btnAdicionarItem.getStyle().set("margin-top", "-3em");
    btnAdicionarItem.addClickListener(e -> {
        adicionaNovoItem();
    });
```

mas como implementar este metodo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
package br.com.fjsistemas.cadastros.view;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.vaadin.textfieldformatter.CustomStringBlockFormatter;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.datepicker.DatePicker;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dialog.Dialog;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.GridVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tab;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.NumberField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.PropertyId;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.NumberRenderer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

import br.com.fjsistemas.backend.Cliente;
import br.com.fjsistemas.backend.Produto;
import br.com.fjsistemas.backend.Venda;
import br.com.fjsistemas.main.MainView;
import br.com.fjsistemas.repository.ClienteRepository;
import br.com.fjsistemas.repository.ProdutoRepository;
import br.com.fjsistemas.service.VendaService;

@Route(value = "venda-view", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Lançamento de Vendas")
public class VendaView extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private HorizontalLayout hltVenda = new HorizontalLayout();
    Grid<Venda> grdVenda = new Grid<>(Venda.class, false);

    private HorizontalLayout hltBarraBotoes = new HorizontalLayout();
    Button btnNovo = new Button("Novo");
    Button btnAlterar = new Button("Alterar");
    Button btnExcluir = new Button("Excluir");

    private Dialog dlgJanela = new Dialog();

    private FormLayout fltCamposVenda = new FormLayout();

    HorizontalLayout segundaLinhaGuiaVenda = new HorizontalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout terceiraLinhaGuiaVenda = new HorizontalLayout();

    Tab vender = new Tab("Vendas");
    Div venderDiv = new Div();

    Tab entrega = new Tab("Entregas");
    Div entregaDiv = new Div();

    Tab financeiro = new Tab("Financeiro");
    Div financeiroDiv = new Div();

    @PropertyId("data")
    private DatePicker txtDataVenda = new DatePicker("Data Venda");

    @PropertyId("nome")
    private ComboBox<Cliente> txtNomeCliente = new ComboBox<>();

    @PropertyId("telefone")
    private TextField txtTelefone = new TextField("Telefone");

    @PropertyId("celular")
    private TextField txtCelular = new TextField("Celular");

    @PropertyId("campoSomaValores")
    private TextField campoSomaValores = new TextField();

    private HorizontalLayout htlDlgBarraBotoes = new HorizontalLayout();
    private Button btnSalvar = new Button("Salvar");
    private Button btnFechar = new Button("Fechar");
    private Button btnAdicionarItem = new Button("+ Item");

    @Autowired
    VendaService vendaService;

    @Autowired
    ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @Autowired
    ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

    private List<Venda> listaVendas;
    private Venda venda;

    Binder<Venda> binderVenda = new Binder<>(Venda.class);

    public VendaView() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        configuraTela();

    }

    private void configuraTela() {

        setMargin(false);
        setPadding(false);

        configuraHltVenda();
        configuraFltBarraBotoes();
        configuraDlgJanela();
        populaGrdVenda();
        configuraBinder();

        add(hltVenda, hltBarraBotoes);
    }

    private void configuraFltBarraBotoes() {

        btnNovo.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnNovo.addClickListener(e -> {
            novoClick();
        });

        btnAlterar.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnAlterar.addClickListener(e -> {
            alterarClick();
        });

        btnExcluir.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnExcluir.addClickListener(e -> {
            excluirClick();
        });

        hltBarraBotoes.add(btnNovo, btnAlterar, btnExcluir);
    }

    private void excluirClick() {

        if (venda != null) {
            listaVendas.remove(venda);
            vendaService.delete(venda);
            atualizaGrdVenda();
        }
    }

    private void configuraHltVenda() {
        hltVenda.setWidthFull();
        configuraGrdVenda();
        hltVenda.add(grdVenda);
    }

    private void configuraGrdVenda() {
        grdVenda.setHeight("820px");
        grdVenda.setWidthFull();

        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getId).setHeader("ID:").setAutoWidth(true);

        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getDataVenda).setHeader("Data Venda:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("dataVenda");

        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getNomeCliente).setHeader("Nome:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("nome");
        
        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getTelefone).setHeader("Telefone:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("telefone");
        
        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getCelular).setHeader("Celular:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("celular");

        grdVenda.addColumn(new NumberRenderer<>(Venda::getValorTotalVenda, "R$ %(,.2f", Locale.getDefault(), "R$ 0.00"))
                .setHeader("Valor Total:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("valorTotalVenda");

        grdVenda.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_COMPACT, GridVariant.LUMO_COLUMN_BORDERS);

        grdVenda.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true).setResizable(true));

        grdVenda.addItemClickListener(e -> {
            venda = e.getItem();
        });

    }

    private void configuraDlgJanela() {

        dlgJanela.setHeight("755px");
        dlgJanela.setWidth("860px");

//=====================================================================================================================
        
        txtNomeCliente.setWidth("350px");
        txtNomeCliente.setLabel("Nome Cliente");
        
        List<Cliente> listaDeClientes = clienteRepository.findAll();
        txtNomeCliente.setItemLabelGenerator(Cliente::getNome);
        txtNomeCliente.setItems(listaDeClientes);
        txtNomeCliente.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            txtTelefone.setValue(event.getValue().getFone());
            txtCelular.setValue(event.getValue().getCelular());
        });

        new CustomStringBlockFormatter.Builder().blocks(0, 2, 4, 4).delimiters("(", ")", "-").numeric().build()
                .extend(txtTelefone);

        new CustomStringBlockFormatter.Builder().blocks(0, 2, 5, 4).delimiters("(", ")", "-").numeric().build()
                .extend(txtCelular);

//=====================================================================================================================

        Label text = new Label("Valor Total da Compra");
        text.getElement().getStyle().set("fontWeight", "bold");
        text.getStyle().set("margin-top", "2em");
        text.getStyle().set("margin-left", "2em");
        text.getStyle().set("text-align", "center");
        campoSomaValores.getStyle().set("margin-top", "2em");
        campoSomaValores.getStyle().set("margin-right", "1em");
        campoSomaValores.setWidth("30em");

//==========================================================================================================================    

        segundaLinhaGuiaVenda.add(txtNomeCliente, txtTelefone, txtCelular);

        fltCamposVenda.add(venderDiv, entregaDiv, financeiroDiv);
        venderDiv.add(txtDataVenda, segundaLinhaGuiaVenda);
        venderDiv.getStyle().set("height", "600px");
        venderDiv.getStyle().set("width", "800px");
        venderDiv.getStyle().set("overflow-y", "scroll");
        
        vender.add(venderDiv);

        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        txtDataVenda.setValue(now);

        Map<Tab, Component> tabsToPages = new HashMap<>();
        tabsToPages.put(vender, venderDiv);
        tabsToPages.put(entrega, entregaDiv);
        tabsToPages.put(financeiro, financeiroDiv);
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(vender, entrega, financeiro);
        Div pages = new Div(venderDiv, entregaDiv, financeiroDiv);

        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
            tabsToPages.values().forEach(page -> page.setVisible(false));
            Component selectedPage = tabsToPages.get(tabs.getSelectedTab());
            selectedPage.setVisible(true);
        });

        dlgJanela.add(tabs, pages);

        btnSalvar.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnSalvar.getStyle().set("margin-top", "2em");
        btnSalvar.getStyle().set("margin-left", "1em");
        btnSalvar.addClickListener(e -> {
            salvarClick();
        });

        btnFechar.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnFechar.getStyle().set("margin-top", "2em");
        btnFechar.addClickListener(e -> {
            dlgJanela.close();
        });

        btnAdicionarItem.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnAdicionarItem.getStyle().set("margin-top", "2em");
        btnAdicionarItem.addClickListener(e -> {
            adicionaProduto();
        });

        htlDlgBarraBotoes.add(btnSalvar, btnFechar, btnAdicionarItem, text, campoSomaValores);

        dlgJanela.add(fltCamposVenda, htlDlgBarraBotoes);
    }

    private void salvarClick() {

        venda = binderVenda.getBean();

        boolean adicionarLista = venda.getId() == null ? true : false;

        vendaService.create(venda);

        if (adicionarLista) {
            listaVendas.add(venda);
        }
        atualizaGrdVenda();
        novaVenda();
        txtNomeCliente.focus();

        binderVenda.setBean(venda);

        if (adicionarLista) {
            dlgJanela.close();
        }
    }

    private void populaGrdVenda() {

        listaVendas = vendaService.read();
        atualizaGrdVenda();
    }

    private void atualizaGrdVenda() {
        grdVenda.setItems(listaVendas);
    }

    private void configuraBinder() {

        binderVenda.bindInstanceFields(this);

    }

    private void novoClick() {

        novaVenda();
        binderVenda.setBean(venda);

        dlgJanela.open();
        txtNomeCliente.focus();
    }

    private void alterarClick() {

        if (venda != null) {
            binderVenda.setBean(venda);

            dlgJanela.open();

        }
    }

    private void adicionaProduto() {

        ComboBox<Produto> txtProdutos = new ComboBox<>();

        NumberField txtQuantidade = new NumberField("Quantidade");

        TextField txtValorUnitario = new TextField("Valor Unitário");

        TextField txtValorTotalItem = new TextField("Valor Total Item");

        txtProdutos.setWidth("370px");
        txtProdutos.setLabel("Produtos");
        List<Produto> listaDeProdutos = produtoRepository.findAll();
        txtProdutos.setItemLabelGenerator(Produto::getNome);
        txtProdutos.setItems(listaDeProdutos);
        txtProdutos.addValueChangeListener(event -> {

            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
            try {

                txtValorUnitario.setValue(formatter.format(event.getValue().getValor()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

//==========================================================================================================================

        txtQuantidade.setHasControls(true);
        txtQuantidade.setValue(null);
        txtQuantidade.setMin(1);

        txtQuantidade.addValueChangeListener(event -> {

            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
            double valorTotal = 0;
            try {
                valorTotal = formatter.parse(txtValorUnitario.getValue()).doubleValue() * txtQuantidade.getValue();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            txtValorTotalItem.setValue(formatter.format(valorTotal));
            campoSomaValores.setValue(formatter.format(valorTotal));
        });

        HorizontalLayout linhaNova = new HorizontalLayout();
        linhaNova.add(txtProdutos, txtQuantidade, txtValorUnitario, txtValorTotalItem);

        venderDiv.add(linhaNova);
    

    }

    private void novaVenda() {
        venda = new Venda();
        venda.setNomeCliente(" ");
        dlgJanela.close();

    }
}
```